# iptables блокирует все исходящие соединения

Tags: linux, iptables

Я захотел сделать так, чтобы к моему ноутбуку можно было подключиться только через порт 43210. Я это сделал следующими командами (до этого таблица была абсолютно пустой и разрешала все пакеты):

```bsh
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 43210 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

И вроде все заработало: подключение (проверил с телефона) работает только по порту 43210. Но вот проблема заключается в том, что после этого блокируются все исходящие соединения на самом ноутбуке (я даже сам к себе не могу подключиться, что уж говорить о разных сайтах, серверах, и т.п.)

Почему это происходит, и как это исправить?

Вот как выглядит таблица после этих команд:

```sh
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:43210
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ещё надо первым правилом в INPUT добавить приём пакетов для установленных соединений:

`iptables -I INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT`

Кроме того, добавьте разрешение на работу через loopback:

`iptables -I INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT`

Если со вторым правилом всё очевидно, то с первым, видимо, требуются пояснения.

Сейчас, если вы пытаетесь открыть исходящее соединение, происходит следующее (рассмотрим на примере TCP):

1. Вы посылаете TCP-пакет с флагом SYN например на порт 80 адреса 123.45.67.89. Вы его посылаете со своего адреса и с какого-то случайным образом выбранного системой порта из диапазона 1024-65534.
2. Удалённый хост вам отвечает пакетом с флагами SYN и ACK на ваш адрес и порт, с которого вы открывали соединение.
3. Этот пакет выбрасывается вашим фаероволлом, потому что он с вероятностью "дофига" идёт НЕ на ваш порт 43210.
4. Попытка исходящего соединения закрывается по тайм-ауту после пары повторов попытки.

Comment: вероятность тут не «дофига», а ровно «единица». ведь порт 43210 уже слушает какой-то локальный процесс.

Answer (score -1):

Ну можно попробовать открыть порты на исходящий трафик.
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

Comment: Они уже открыты

Comment: А может исходящие есть? просто отклик на эти запросы теперь игнорируется, или на все запросы приходит ответ через порт 43210? Сами к себе вы через этот порт подключаться пробуете?

Comment: Я пробовал подключаться и к себе через этот порт, и через остальные порты, и к любому стороннему серверу, все соединения блокируются (Я добавил в вопрос то, как выглядит таблица, при которой это происходит)